# Preprocess the Linux source code and save to another directory

Tags: linux, kernel, c, gcc, cpp

Suppose I have the entire Linux source code in `/tmp/linux-src`.

After `menuconfig` I want to do "some kind of `gcc -E`" where all the preprocessor macros other than `#include` are expanded so the *actual configured preprocessed source code* (for compilation) will be saved in `/tmp/linux-src-to-compile` - not in single file but rather keeping the whole tree structure leaving out the files that are not needed.

Is this kind of trickery possible? Is it also possible when prepping for cross-compilation?

Thanks

Comment: Why not process the `#include` directives? If you allow that, then yes, this is possible; otherwise I don’t think so.